# File Upload Utility using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a webpage I'm building to allow users to upload multiple files to my webserver.  Its a simple html page and php script.  I'm having php errors and i'm not sure why. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my html.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    Your Name:
    <select name="uname">
    <option value="Test">Test</option>
    </select>
<br>
    Your Company:
    <select name="company">
    <option value="TestCom">testCompany</option>
    </select>
<br>
    Choose file(s) to upload (Max 500MB): 
    <input name="files[]" type="file" id="files" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my php

```
<?php
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$dir = "D:/File Upload/uploads/$uname/$company/";
$count = 0;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($_FILES['files']))
{
  // loop all files
  foreach ( $_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name )
  {
    // if file not uploaded then skip it
    if ( !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i]) )
      continue;

    // now we can move uploaded files
      if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $dir . $name) )
        $count++;
  }

  echo json_encode(array('count' => $count));

}
?>
```

Here is the errors in the php log.

```
[11-Feb-2015 16:01:04 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(D:/File Upload/uploads/Test/TestCom/image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\File Upload\upload.php on line 17
[11-Feb-2015 16:01:04 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'D:\phptempdata\php48F.tmp' to 'D:/File Upload/uploads/Test/TestCom/image.png' in D:\File Upload\upload.php on line 17
```

Comment: Using user input in paths without any verification is very dangerous.

Comment: I will add the logic to vet user input after I can just get the upload to work.

Comment: Could it be because the following folders do not exist? D:/File Upload/uploads/Test/TestCom/

Comment: Your correct.  I had been working so hard on just getting the file uploaded, I don't stop to ask if the folder was actually there.  I added this line to create the folder if it didn't exist.  
 if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
 }

Comment: If you answered your own question, consider posting your answer as an answer and accepting it.  This both helps future readers who find this question by search and keeps future answerers from wasting time on a question you don't help with anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have the directories specified actually created on the files system.

I had been working so hard on just getting the file uploaded, I don't stop to ask if the folder was actually there.

I added this line to create the folder if it didn't exist.

```
if (!file_exists($dir)) { mkdir($dir, 0777, true); }
```